# Pulseaudio module-remap-source add 2 seconds latency

Tags: linux, pulse-audio

I am facing issue which the module-remap-source will auto add 2 seconds latency to a sink.
I used module-null-sink create a sink and use the remap to create a virtual source which use the sink as input. But, the virtual source will add 2 seconds delay. I don't know how to control the laytency.
Here is the "pactl list sources" output

```
State: RUNNING
        Name: virtmic_sink.monitor
        Description: Monitor of Virtual_Microphone_Sink
        Driver: module-null-sink.c
        Sample Specification: s16le 1ch 44100Hz
        Channel Map: mono
        Owner Module: 34
        Mute: no
        Volume: mono: 22359 /  34% / -28.02 dB
                balance 0.00
        Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        Monitor of Sink: virtmic_sink
        Latency: 0 usec, configured 2000000 usec
        Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY
        Properties:
                device.description = "Monitor of Virtual_Microphone_Sink"
                device.class = "monitor"
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        Formats:
                pcm
Source #15
        State: IDLE
        Name: virtmic
        Description: Virtual_Microphone
        Driver: module-remap-source.c
        Sample Specification: s16le 1ch 44100Hz
        Channel Map: mono
        Owner Module: 36
        Mute: no
        Volume: mono: 36700 /  56% / -15.11 dB
                balance 0.00
        Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        Monitor of Sink: n/a
        Latency: 0 usec, configured 2000000 usec
        Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY
        Properties:
                device.master_device = "virtmic_sink.monitor"
                device.class = "filter"
                device.description = "Virtual_Microphone"
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        Formats:
                pcm
```

In the Latency, it says configured 2000000 usec, how I can config it?